# C Program for Ramanujan-like Number Series

Tags: c, hardy-ramanujan

**1729** is known as the **Ramanujan number**, after an anecdote of the British mathematician *G. H. Hardy* when he visited Indian mathematician *Srinivasa Ramanujan* in hospital. He related their conversation:
"I remember once going to see him when he was ill at Putney. I had ridden in taxi cab number 1729 and remarked that the number seemed to me rather a dull one, and that I hoped it was not an unfavourable omen. "No," he replied, "it is a very interesting number; it is the smallest number expressible as the sum of two cubes in two different ways." 
The two different ways are:
 
*1729 = 1^3 + 12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3*
(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number))
Next such number is **4104**.
*4104 = 16^3 + 2^3 = 9^3 + 15^3*
I want to find more such numbers. I have tried several time but not able to write code for it. The codes I have written didn't run.

Comment: Show us what you have tried,then we will help.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Gaurav Bahadur Yes I will add my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although, You must have shown your work.
Try it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i, a, b, x, y, k;

printf("Input nos. between which you want to find Ramanujan No.: ");
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

for(i=a;i<b;i++){
    k=0;
    for(x=1;x*x*x<i;x++){
        for(y=x+1;x*x*x+y*y*y<=i;y++){

            if(x*x*x+y*y*y==i){
                 k++;
                 x++;           
            }
        }

    }
     if(k==2){
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```